# How to make function signature? ERC223 ContractReceiver

Tags: solidity, signature, fallback-function, erc-223

Hi what does these lines mean?

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) {
    ...
    uint32 u = uint32(_data[3]) + (uint32(_data[2]) << 8) + (uint32(_data[1]) << 16) + (uint32(_data[0]) << 24);
    tkn.sig = bytes4(u);
}
```

I know tkn.sig is the 4 bytes signature of function. But could someone explain how those two lines work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays
Fixed-size byte arrays
bytes1, bytes2, bytes3, …, bytes32. byte is an alias for bytes1.
----------------==
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array
Dynamically-sized byte array
bytes: Dynamically-sized byte array, see Arrays. Not a value-type!
----------------==
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#arrays
Variables of type bytes and string are special arrays. A bytes is similar to byte[], but it is packed tightly in calldata. string is equal to bytes but does not allow length or index access (for now).
So bytes should always be preferred over byte[] because it is cheaper.
----------------==
So the argument bytes _data means:
 _data is a Dynamically-sized byte array, and each element is of type byte1
 _data[3], _data[2], _data[1], _data[0] are the first 4 elements of _data
uint32(_data[3]) is to convert _data[3] into a number of uint32
----------------==
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#integers
** (exponentiation), << (left shift), >> (right shift)
The expression x << y is equivalent to x * 2**y, and x >> y is equivalent to x / 2**y
----------------==
So
uint32(_data[2]) << 8 is equivalent to uint32(_data[2]) * 2**8 
the same for _data[1] and _data[0]
then add them all together to make uint32 u
then convert u into bytes4 by bytes4(u)
Wow, that is complicated ... I hope I didn't make any mistakes :)

Comment: That all looks right.

Answer (score 1):

`tokenFallback` receives a third parameter, `_data`, which can be any arbitrary data. How it gets interpreted by the contract is very much contract-specific. The code you pasted seems to just be converting the first four bytes of `_data` into a `bytes4` to store at `tkn.sig`. I can't speculate as to why without seeing the rest of the code. (E.g., it would be interesting to see how `tkn` is being used.)

**EDIT**

It looks like the code comes from https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/blob/Recommended/Receiver_Interface.sol#L17. The rest of the function, including the comment, is illuminating:

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data){
    TKN memory tkn;
    tkn.sender = _from;
    tkn.value = _value;
    tkn.data = _data;
    uint32 u = uint32(_data[3]) + (uint32(_data[2]) << 8) + (uint32(_data[1]) << 16) + (uint32(_data[0]) << 24);
    tkn.sig = bytes4(u);

    /* tkn variable is analogue of msg variable of Ether transaction
    *  tkn.sender is person who initiated this token transaction   (analogue of msg.sender)
    *  tkn.value the number of tokens that were sent   (analogue of msg.value)
    *  tkn.data is data of token transaction   (analogue of msg.data)
    *  tkn.sig is 4 bytes signature of function
    *  if data of token transaction is a function execution
    */
}
```

I surmise that `_data` here is being treated like in a non-token scenario, where the first four bytes are a function selector (the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function signature). Presumably this is so the token receiver can invoke a function to handle the inbound tokens, much like a `payable` function handles inbound transactions.